# Getting text element XML Node based on element name C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to create a function that will take an XML file and split it into its individual elements. Then depending on the element name I want to store the text from that element in an array. My function so far is:

```
public string[] read(string fileLoc)
{
    //Create variables
    r = XmlReader.Create(fileLoc, settingsR);
    string[] content = new string[3];

    while (r.Read())
    {
        if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            switch (r.Name)
            {
                case "Title":
                    content[0] = r.Name;
                    break;
                case "Description":
                    content[1] = r.Name;
                    break;
                default:
                    content[2] = r.Name;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

So far I can load the array with the name of the element, but not the text. Thanks

Comment: Use XDocument and XElement and you are almost done.  Those are the linq to xml classes

Comment: The text is returned in r.Value.

Comment: HOW DID I NOT SEE r.Value!?

Thank you!